# How to use subfields from ADT fields in cxGrid?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I',m trying to use some ADT subfields added in a `TFDQuery` in a TcxGrid. When i add a column using a subfield from a ADT Field, the column don't show the field value and the field is Ready Only.
How to use correctly this field type in a cxgrid?

how to reproduce:

1. Create a table in database like (i'm using Postgres):

   `create table test (id integer, name text);`
2. In Delphi, Create a TFDQuery with a SQL text:

   `select test from test`
3. Add the ADT field (test) in Field Editor. So, test.id and test.name will be created as individual fields too.
4. Then add a `TcxGrid` in a form and create a Tableview adding the FDQuery's columns of step 3 (you can't do it automaticaly by "Retrieve Fields" Option on gridview editor).
5. The issue: columns don't shows the field value, but the ADT column (test) like a record values

Ps: Using `TDBGrid` can show and edit the individual columns, but i need to use `TcxGrid`.

Comment: I doubt this q is answerable unless you provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what you are attempting, including some data which is used to populate the database table(s) which the FDQuery queries to create the ADT field.

Comment: @MartynA Thanks. mvce added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want show subfields of the ADT field as individual columns, the `TFDQuery.ObjectView` property must be set to `false` ([Displaying_ADT](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Displaying_ADT_and_Array_Fields)). In this way, you can automatically or manually add the subfields present in the ADT field, and additionally, edit them individually in the `TcxGrid`.

Comment: Yes @ MartynA. We were looking for the solution together.